# Multiplying data value with Jquery

Tags: jquery, multiplication

I have some checkboxes that look like this:

I want to multiply the data-raw-price & data-price with 3, when i select a bigger size in a dropdown.

I tried something like this:

```js
    $(document).on('change', '#pa_size', function() {

      if ($("#pa_size").val() == "32cm-normal") {
        var value = parseFloat($(".addon-checkbox").data('price').val());
        $(".addon-checkbox").data('price').val(value * 3);
      } else {

        $(".addon-checkbox").data('price');
      }


    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="pa_size" class="" name="attribute_pa_size" data-attribute_name="attribute_pa_size">
  <option value="" selected="selected">Válassz egy lehetőséget</option>
  <option value="32cm-normal" class="attached enabled" selected="selected">32 cm (normál)</option>
  <option value="52cm-csaladi" class="attached enabled">52 cm (családi)</option>
</select>
<input type="checkbox" class="addon addon-checkbox" name="addon-4851-husok-2[]" data-raw-price="250" data-price="250" value="sonka">
```

But i'm really not sure how to address those values and muliply.

Thx

Comment: What is `#pa_size`? Please add more code.

Comment: pa_size is the 2 size of a pizza

<select id="pa_size" class="" name="attribute_pa_size" data-attribute_name="attribute_pa_size"><option value="" selected="selected">Válassz egy lehetőséget</option><option value="32cm-normal" class="attached enabled" selected="selected">32 cm (normál)</option><option value="52cm-csaladi" class="attached enabled">52 cm (családi)</option></select>

Comment: Update your question. Do not add it as a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use `val()`. You get the data attribute without that, also it won't work using `val()`.

So change:

```
parseFloat($(".addon-checkbox").data('price')).val();
```

to this:

```
parseFloat($(".addon-checkbox").data('price'));
```

Also **[data()](https://api.jquery.com/data/)** does not update data attribute of an element, it only allocates it in memory. You need to use **[attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)** for this and it should work.

Try this:

```js
$(document).on('change', '#pa_size', function() {
  if ($("#pa_size").val() == "32cm-normal") {
    var dataPrice = parseFloat($(".addon-checkbox").data('price'));
    $(".addon-checkbox").attr('data-price', dataPrice * 3);
    console.log($(".addon-checkbox").attr('data-price'));
  } else {
     $(".addon-checkbox").data('price');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="pa_size" class="" name="attribute_pa_size" data-attribute_name="attribute_pa_size">
  <option value="" selected="selected">Válassz egy lehetőséget</option>
  <option value="32cm-normal" class="attached enabled">32 cm (normál)</option>
  <option value="52cm-csaladi" class="attached enabled">52 cm (családi)</option>
</select>
<input type="checkbox" class="addon addon-checkbox" name="addon-4851-husok-2[]" data-raw-price="250" data-price="250" value="sonka">
```

Comment: Thats simple changes the value from "sonka" to 300, and not the data-price to 250*3=750

Comment: Ok, looks fine, i can see the right value in the console, but in the html the values not changing. It needs to be upadted or something?

Comment: @SzékelyTamás, see again, I've just updated my answer. You need to use `attr('data-price', dataPrice * 3)` instead of `data('price', dataPrice * 3)` because `data()` only  asigns value to memory, and not actually updating the DOM element.

Comment: @SzékelyTamás did this answer your question? If so consider accepting it.

Answer (score 0):

First, I would use

```
$(#pa_size).on('change',function()
```

Then dont use val(), use data like this:

```
$(".addon-checkbox").data('price', value*3)
```

Your function should look like this:

```
$('#pa_size').on('change',function() {

    if($("#pa_size").val()=="32cm-normal")   {
        var value = parseFloat($(".addon-checkbox").data('price'));
        $(".addon-checkbox").data('price', value*3);
    }
    else{
       $(".addon-checkbox").data('price');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
var valRawPrice = parseFloat($(".addon-checkbox").data('raw-price'));
var valPrice = parseFloat($(".addon-checkbox").data('price'));
```

Now, further use these 2 varaiables i.e. *valRawPrice* & *valPrice* and do the further multiplication.
Please vote if the solution is helpful.

**Thanks!**